# Ошибка при написании проги из Java Headfirst

Tags: java, head

Текст ошибки

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Checkbox.ser (Не удается найти указанный файл)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:220)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:158)
at BeatBox$MyReadInListener.actionPerformed(BeatBox.java:192)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:270)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6589)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6354)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2261)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4966)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2319)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4798)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4914)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4543)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4484)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2305)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4798)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$600(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at BeatBox$MyReadInListener.actionPerformed(BeatBox.java:198)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:270)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6589)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6354)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2261)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4966)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2319)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4798)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4914)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4543)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4484)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2305)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4798)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$600(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Process finished with exit code 0

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class BeatBox {
JPanel mainPanel;
ArrayList<JCheckBox> checkboxList;
Sequencer sequencer;
Sequence sequence;
Track track;
JFrame theFrame;
String[] instrumentNames = {"Bass Drum", "Closed Hi-Hat", "Open Hi-Hat", "Acoustic Share", "Crash Cymbal", "Hand Clap", "High Tom", "Hi Bongo", "Maracas", "Whistle", "Low Conga", "Cowbell", "Vibraslap", "Low-mid Tom", "High Agogo", "Open Hi Conga"};
int[] instruments = {35, 42, 46, 38, 49, 39, 50, 60, 70, 72, 64, 56, 58, 47, 67, 63};
public static void main (String args[]) {
    new BeatBox().buildGUI();
}
public void buildGUI() {
    theFrame = new JFrame ("Cyber BeatBox");
    theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
    JPanel background = new JPanel (layout);
    background.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
    checkboxList = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
    Box buttonBox = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    JButton start = new JButton ("Start");
    start.addActionListener (new MyStartListener());
    buttonBox.add(start);
    JButton stop = new JButton ("Stop");
    stop.addActionListener (new MyStopListener());
    buttonBox.add(stop);

    JButton upTempo = new JButton ("Tempo Up");
    start.addActionListener (new MyUpTempoListener());
    buttonBox.add(upTempo);

    JButton serializeit = new JButton("SerializeIt");
    start.addActionListener(new MySendListener());
    buttonBox.add(serializeit);

    JButton restore = new JButton("restore");
    start.addActionListener(new MyReadInListener());
    buttonBox.add(restore);


    JButton downTempo = new JButton ("Tempo Down");
    start.addActionListener (new MyDownTempoListener());
    buttonBox.add(downTempo);

    Box nameBox = new Box (BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    for (int i =0; i<16; i++) {
        nameBox.add(new Label (instrumentNames[i]));
    }
    background.add(BorderLayout.EAST, buttonBox);
    background.add(BorderLayout.WEST, nameBox);
    theFrame.getContentPane().add(background);
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout (16, 16);
    grid.setVgap(1);
    grid.setHgap(2);
    mainPanel = new JPanel (grid);
    background.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++) {
        JCheckBox c= new JCheckBox();
        c.setSelected(false);
        checkboxList.add(c);
        mainPanel.add(c);
    }
    setUpMidi();
    theFrame.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 300);
    theFrame.pack();
    theFrame.setVisible(true);
}
public void setUpMidi() {
    try {
        sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        sequencer.open();
        sequence = new Sequence (Sequence.PPQ, 4);
        track = sequence.createTrack();
        sequencer.setTempoInBPM(120);
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
public void buildTrackAndStart() {
    int[] trackList = null;
    sequence.deleteTrack(track);
    track = sequence.createTrack();
    for (int i=0; i<16; i++) {
        trackList = new int[16];
        int key = instruments[i];
        for (int j=0; j<16; j++) {
            JCheckBox jc = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(j+(16*i));
            if (jc.isSelected()) {
                trackList[j] = key; }
            else {
                trackList[j] =0;
            }
        }
        makeTracks (trackList);
        track.add(makeEvent(176,1,127,0,16));
    }
    track.add(makeEvent(192,9,1,0,15));
    try {
        sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
        sequencer.setLoopCount(sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        sequencer.start();
        sequencer.setTempoInBPM(120);
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

private class MyStartListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        buildTrackAndStart();
    }
}
private class MyStopListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent a) {
        sequencer.stop();
    }
}
public class MyUpTempoListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        float tempoFactor = sequencer.getTempoFactor();
        sequencer.setTempoFactor((float) (tempoFactor * 1.03));
    }
}
public class MyDownTempoListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        float tempoFactor = sequencer.getTempoFactor();
        sequencer.setTempoFactor((float) (tempoFactor * .97));
    }









}
public void makeTracks (int[] list) {
    for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        int key = list[i];
        if (key !=0) {
            track.add(makeEvent(144,9,key, 100, i));
            track.add(makeEvent(144,9,key, 100, i+1));
        }
    }
}

public MidiEvent makeEvent (int comd, int chan, int one, int two, int tick) {
    MidiEvent event = null;
    try {
        ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
        a.setMessage(comd, chan, one, two);
        event = new MidiEvent(a, tick);
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return event;
}
public class MySendListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        boolean[] checkboxState = new boolean[256];
        for (int i = 0; i <256   ; i++) {
            JCheckBox check =(JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(i);
            if (check.isSelected()){
                checkboxState[i] = true;

            }

        }
        try{
            FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("CheckBox.ser"));
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
            os.writeObject(checkboxState);

        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class MyReadInListener implements ActionListener{
    public void  actionPerformed (ActionEvent a){
        boolean[] checkboxState = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn= new FileInputStream(new File("Checkbox.ser"));
            ObjectInputStream is =new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            checkboxState = (boolean[]) is.readObject();
        } catch (Exception ex ) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        for (int i = 0; i <256; i++) {
            JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(i);
            if (checkboxState[i]) {
                check.setSelected(true);
            } else {
                check.setSelected(false);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Попробуйте прочитать текст ошибки и расскажите, что в тексте не понятно.

Comment: есть же код создания файла , а пишет что его не видно...

Comment: Создаётся объект типа File, а не файл на диске. При чтении надо проверять, существует ли файл с таким именем.

Comment: Очень интересно , но ответа все ещё не получил.